# How can I launch an application at startup just in a determined session?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, xfce, startup-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Make Program Autostart only In GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086/how-to-make-program-autostart-only-in-gnome)

I set up my Gnome session to use tint2 as a window list panel, but I don't need it when using Xfce, therefore I'd like to have tint2 start only under "Classic Ubuntu" session. Is this possible? Editing the Startup Applications has effect on both sessions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , first place anything autostart file in ~/.config/autostart , and for each *.desktop file need only in GNOME , put a line like this into that file:

> OnlyShowIn=GNOME;

Which means this application will only start in Gnome session.

If you take a look in /etc/xdg/autostart for specific application , thw following image is pretty clear on the basis of its structure:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! As far as you know, is there a way to implement this option to hide desktop launchers in different environments? I tried to appen OnlyShowIn=xy at the bottom of the .desktop files in the Desktop folders but the launchers still show in each session. I'll start a separate question if you don't know.

Comment: some session manager will remember running applications , thus you may need to clear its saved sessions , for xfce , remove ~/.cache/session , for Gnome , i'm not sure